# Linked List in C: "expected expression before 'struct'

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm working on a linked list in C as my first C assignment and I've encountered an obstacle. I'd like another pair of eyes to help me spot what I did wrong.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char *data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Linked_List
{
    struct Node *header;
};

void insertAtBeginning(struct Linkedlist *LL, char ele[])
{
    struct Node new_node = malloc(sizeOf(struct Node)); //error occurs here
}

int main() {
    struct Node head;
    struct Linked_List LL;
    LL.header = &head;
    char string[] = "hello";
    insertAtBeginning(LL, string);
    return 0;
}
```

On the indicated line, I get an error saying `expected expression before 'struct'`.

I am very new to C and don't have a clue as to what could be causing this. My guess is that it has something to do with a misuse of pointers, but I cannot see where I messed up. I'd be very grateful for any and all advice. Thank you all!

Comment: Typo in your function parameter: `Linkedlist` -> `Linked_List`

Comment: `struct Node new_node = malloc(sizeOf(struct Node))` -> `struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node))`

Answer (score 3):

There are several typos (`Linked_List` vs. `LinkedList`, mixing up pointer to structs with structs, `sizeof` vs `sizeOf`).

And you shouldn't have an explicit `struct Node head;`, instead `LL` should be zero initialized and you should treat empty and non empty lists in `insertAtBeginning`.

This is the skeleton of your program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Linked_List
{
    struct Node* header;
};

void insertAtBeginning(struct Linked_List* LL, char ele[])
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
    ...
}

int main() {
    struct Linked_List LL = { 0 };  // 0 initialize the struct
                                    // so `LL.header` is NULL initially.
    char string[] = "hello";
    insertAtBeginning(&LL, string);
    return 0;
}
```

`insertAtBeginning` is still incomplete, here are some hints:

```
void insertAtBeginning(struct Linked_List* LL, char ele[])
{
    struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ... add code to initialize `*new_node`.
    
    if (LL->header == NULL)
    {
        // list is empty
        ... your code 
    }
    else
    {
        // list is non empty
        ... your code
    }
}
```